# Why my shallow comparison in React.memo() is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hey I am making a food delivery app. I am currently implementing cart functionality.
I am stuck memoizing the custom incrementor that I have built it myself. I am using **Flatlist** to render the data:

Here is my CartRowRender code:

```
import React, { useState, memo, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import CartIncrementor from "./CartIncrementor";
import Incrementor from "./Incrementor";


const CartRowRender = ({ item }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.cardItems}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
          <CartIncrementor
            value={item.quantity}
            id={item.id}
            subDataId={item.subDataId}
            price={item.price}
          />
          <View style={styles.priceView}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>₹ {item.quantityPrice}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

function checkEqualProps(prevProps, nextProps) {
  console.log(prevProps, nextProps);
  console.log(
    "Equal quantity Price",
    prevProps.quantityPrice == nextProps.quantityPrice,
    "Equal quantity",
    prevProps.quantity == nextProps.quantity
  );
   return prevProps.quantityPrice === nextProps.quantityPrice;
}
export default memo(CartRowRender, checkEqualProps);
```

For some reasons the shallow comparison doesn't seems to work. When I console log out the function **checkEqualProps** it shows that the previous quantity and the next quantity are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out two things yet only using one thing for the return value. Do you maybe mean

```
return (
  prevProps.quantityPrice === nextProps.quantityPrice &&
  prevProps.quantity === nextProps.quantity
);
```

?

Comment: I think that this works, but the problem is total price of the item changes, but the incrementor value and its price stays the same.